# How can I calculate the RGB value of a grey colour?

Tags: image, colors, dicom, grayscale

I am writing some code to create an image from pixel data stored in a medical image file (DICOM). Essentially, I have a two dimensional array (rows x columns) where each element of the array contains the colour of the pixel at that region in the image. The element values vary between 0 (black) and 1 (white). Values between 0-1 are differing shades of grey.

The language I am using (Xojo) allows me to set the colour of an individual pixel on a canvas but only using the RGB or HSV colour space.

How would I, for instance, get the HSV value for my pixel value of 0.9 (which would be a reasonably "light" shade of grey)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the HSV color value of

- H = 0
- S = 0
- V = your pixel value of 0.9

`g.FillColor=HSV(0.0, 0.0, 0.9)` From [Xojo Documentation](http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/HSV)

See the Image [HSV@wikipedia.org](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV-Farbraum) in the top right corner.